# How to convert a Method into a lambda reference

Tags: java, junit5

I'm writing some jUnit5 extensions to make it easier to test some code.
The extension has these annotations:

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Test
@ExtendWith({CustomJunit5Extension.class})
public @interface MyAnnotation {
   String jsonFile;
   Class<?> converter;
}

// test case
class Test {
   @MyAnnotation(converter = MyClass.class)
   void someTest();
}

// Some class which contains a converter method annotated with @JsonConverterMethod
public class MyClass {
    @JsonConverterMethod
    public static Car converter(String jsonLine);
}

// jUnit5 extension
public class CustomJunit5Extension implements ParameterResolver, AfterEachCallback, AfterAllCallback {

   // ultra simplified version
   public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext pctx, ExtensionContext ectx) throws ParameterResolutionException {
      final MyAnnotation annotation = getAnnotation(pctx, ectx);
      final Method converterMethod = getMethodByAnnotation(annotation.converter(), JsonConverterMethod.class);

      @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
      final var converter = needs to become a 
                            direct reference to MyClass::converter
                            without hardcoding it, because you can
                            have other classes providing different
                            jsonString to Object converters;

      final JsonCandleProvider provider = new JsonCandleProvider(resource, converter);

      return provider;
   }

}
```

Hence the question - how to convert a `Method` reference into a `Lambda` reference so I could pass it to the `MyJsonProvider`? Or how would you achieve a similar result in another way maybe?

Comment: The target of the argument in the `MyJsonProvider` must be a functional interface of the appropriate type whether it is a lambda or a method reference.

Comment: Yes, it should be. But how do you convert the typing from a `Method` ? I can't just hard-code `new MyJsonProvider(resource, MyClass::converter)` into the extension. I need to somehow pass it dynamically. Hence the annotations. :)

Comment: Does the method already take a Functional interface or just the argument to be processed?   And passing a lambda still requires that the target method be able to apply some argument which would normally be provided to the method itself. (I.e. the method must also be able to invoke that lambda).

Comment: I've updated the question with more code example -- I hope this would bring more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method parameter needs to be a Functional interface of the type of the method reference.

```
MyMethod(() -> "Hello, World!");

Supplier<String> supplier = () -> "Hello, World!";
MyMethod(supplier);
MyMethod(supplier::get);
MyMethod2(supplier.get());


public static void MyMethod(Supplier<String> sup) {
    System.out.println(sup.get());
}

public static void MyMethod2(String value) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

prints

```
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Hmm... the `Supplier<>` idea might actually work in my case. I'll need a hour or two to confirm and if it does will mark this as the answer . :)

Comment: Ok.  And I am not fluent on using annotations so my help may be limited.  That also gives others more time to weigh in.

Comment: I confirm having a `Supplier` seems to be the only way to go. You would also need to do a few `unchecked` casts because the reference comes from a `java.lang.Method`, but other than that it works for the specific scenario. Thanks for the help! :)